# Api Java Spring

Tags: java, spring

Пытаюсь получить с этого сайта ответ 
https://some-random-api.ml/facts/dog
Должен приходить джейсон, но приходит 403 статусный код, не понимаю, в чем ошибка

```
   @GetMapping("/shelter")
public String getShelterPage(Authentication authentication, Model model){
    if(authentication != null){
        String a  =  getJSON("https://some-random-api.ml/facts/dog");
        String fact = null;
        if (a != null) {
            fact = a.substring(9,a.length()-3);
        }
        model.addAttribute("authentication", authentication);
        model.addAttribute("fact",fact);
        System.out.println(a);
    }
    return "shelter";
}
    public static String getJSON(String urle) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urle);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
        con.setConnectTimeout(30000);

        con.connect();

        int resp = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println(resp);
        if(resp == 200) {


            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append("\n");
            }
            br.close();

            return sb.toString();
        } else {
            /*Log.e("RESP", "Ответ сервера: " + resp);*/
        }

    } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    return null;
}
```

}

freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> fact  [in template "shelter.ftlh" at line 20, column 22]

### Tip: If the failing expression is known to legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??

---

FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):

### - Failed at: ${fact}  [in template "shelter.ftlh" at line 20, column 20]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все потому, что вы не установили юзер агента. Добавьте эту строку и все заработает

```
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
```

Вот код для того, чтобы проверить, что 403 действительно нет без спринга и прочих зависимостей:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getShelterPage();
    }

    //@GetMapping("/shelter")
    public static String getShelterPage(){//(Authentication authentication, Model model) {
        //if (authentication != null) {
            String a = getJSON("https://some-random-api.ml/facts/dog");
            String fact = null;
            if (a != null) {
                fact = a.substring(9, a.length() - 3);
            }
            //model.addAttribute("authentication", authentication);
            //model.addAttribute("fact", fact);
            System.out.println(a);
        //}
        return "shelter";
    }

    public static String getJSON(String urle) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urle);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
            con.setConnectTimeout(30000);

            con.connect();

            int resp = con.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println(resp);
            if (resp == 200) {

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                String line;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                    sb.append("\n");
                }
                br.close();

                return sb.toString();
            } else {
                /*Log.e("RESP", "Ответ сервера: " + resp);*/
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: не помогло, шаблон пишет, что не может найти переменную, может дело в контроллере? прикрепила выше, вдруг сможете помочь

Comment: @Tanya что значит не помогло? у вас может быть сотня проблем в коде. вы спросили , почему 403 ошибка, а 403 приходит именно по той причине, которую я указал. сейчас в вашем сообщении об ошибке я никакой 403 ошибки не вижу, я вообще не понимаю, зачем вы лезите на столь низкий уровень при отправке запроса, когда у вас спринг под руками. RestTemplate есть, Можно что-то подключить. Я, к примеру, использую ретрофит

Comment: @Tanya ответ я изменил и добавтл код для того, чтобы вы могли его проверить и убедиться, что причина 403 именно в том, о чем я говорил.

Comment: спасибо за помощь, разобралась, помимо того, что у меня не было юзер-аджента, у меня там стояла проверка на аутентификацию глупая, спасибо за помощь еще раз!

Comment: @Tanya не за что. удачи вам